# Traffic light in Javalogo

Tags: java

I need to make an traffic light in Javalogo, which is a combination of a few libraries that can be found [here:](http://www.edu-actief.nl/javalogo/download.htm). In this first stage I need to make a traffic light that starts on red, get's green 7 seconds later, orange 5 seconds later and 2 seconds later red again. In the end stage of this first project I need to fade the colors, but that's not that important now.

I made two different classes to try building this in. You can find the code of the first [here](http://cl.ly/text/0j2o2X2N2y1l). I can't post the second because of spam prevention, I'll try to post it in a reply.

**A little introduction to javalogo, and used variables**
    vooruit: movement of a given number of points
    penAan(): give the pixel/movement a color (black)
    penUit(): end of penAan()
    vulAan(): fill the created square/circle/etc. with a color
    vulUit(): end of vulAan()
    hoek: angle
    stap: the number of points 'vooruit' moves
    rechts(): angle to the right
    left(): angle to the left
    groen: green
    oranje: orange
rood: red
Stoplight: traffic light

Thanks in advance,
Raimond

Comment: Second code: http://cl.ly/2U462u2y3f2Z

Comment: Just found these things: I need to use a if-than-else construction and a command called pauze() (Dutch for pause), I'm going to invest the latter.

Comment: If it's homework, [tag it as such](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @martijno done, you could still give me a full answer, as I'm allowed to use this kind a boards. I'll just list the tread as a source.

Comment: well done. And what was the question again?